# Optimize jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I just want me to know how is it possible to optimize this code snippet?

```
$('#datedebut').change(function() {
    if (Date.parse($('#datefin').val()) - Date.parse($(this).val()) <= 0) {
        alert('Impossible');
    }
});

$('#datefin').change(function() {
    if (Date.parse($(this).val()) - Date.parse($('#datedebut').val()) <= 0) {
        alert('Impossible');
    }
});
```

I think it is repeating the same thing, but I do not know how to find something that is optimized and of course simple.

Thank you in advance for your proposal.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind looking up the elements again, you could simply do

```
$('#datedebut, #datefin').change(function() {
    if (Date.parse($('#datefin').val()) - Date.parse($('#datedebut').val()) <= 0) {
        alert('Impossible');
    }
});
```

Of course you can also select the elements once and keep references to them...

However, it is not optimization in terms of performance.

Comment: I can't really see a better way to do it! No matter what, both elements will need to be looked up in order to make the comparison. I can imagine a way to cache each lookup so that it's only done once, but then the resulting code is more verbose than it needs to be. Unless it's an iterator running thousands of times, not much need to optimize performance on a trivial function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<input type="text" id="datefin" onchange="validateChange()" />
<input type="text" id="datedebut" onchange="validateChange()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateChange(){
        if (Date.parse($('#datefin').val()) - Date.parse($('#datedebut').val()) <= 0) {
            alert('Impossible');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are generally good to avoid these days.